# Strange Characters Showing in Android Text View

Tags: android, textview

I have a text view that is showing a couple of characters as rectangles and I can't figure out where they are coming from.  Any ideas?

Here is the XML with the text:

```
<item>
Five cents per gallon discount. Go online to www.amerigas.com or yellow pages for the closest AmeriGas location.
\n\n          Offers subject to change without notice, some restrictions may apply, contact store for details. Offer does not apply to fixed price customers. You must provide your Farm Bureau membership number to your AmeriGas dealer prior to delivery of your propane in order to receive the discount.\n
</item>
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

EDIT: In the XML, I notice when I paste it here the is a large space before Offers, which is where the characters are showing up.  That space doesn't show up in my editor though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that after the `\n\n` in the XML file, you have tab or some other odd white-space characters that the font does not handle correctly. Replace them with regular spaces and the little boxes should go away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the special char \n.
Just do this:

```
string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: If the `\n` were the problem, then there would be another box on the screen at the end of the text, where there's another `\n`.

Comment: add this text to your strings file and let me know if it worked.(insted of using it as an item)  
    `<string name="xml">Five cents per gallon discount. Go online to www.amerigas.com or yellow pages for the closest AmeriGas location.
\n\n          Offers subject to change without notice, some restrictions may apply, contact store for details. Offer does not apply to fixed price customers. You must provide your Farm Bureau membership number to your AmeriGas dealer prior to delivery of your propane in order to receive the discount.\n</string>`